# Convert .s file to .midi or any sound file

Tags: music

I have a .s file from a game, I think it contains `Music` . I know this sounds weird but here are snippets :

(I opened it with Visual Studio and it sais it is a 'Assembler Source')

```
.equ    My_File_grp, voicegroup000
    .equ    My_File_pri, 0
    .equ    My_File_rev, 0
    .equ    My_File_mvl, 100
    .equ    My_File_key, 0
    .equ    My_File_tbs, 1
    .equ    My_File_exg, 0
    .equ    My_File_cmp, 1
```

The rest is only stuff like this:

```
@ 001   ----------------------------------------
    .byte       VOICE , 52
    .byte       N36   , An3 
    .byte   W36
    .byte       VOICE , 58
    .byte       N48   , An3 
    .byte   W48
    .byte       VOICE , 54
    .byte       N12   , Fs3 
    .byte   W12
```

I need to listen to this but I really don't understand what these lines of code mean, please help! I want to convert this file to a file I can listen to.

Comment: While the file may be from a game, the problem isn't game development specific. Check out stackoverflow.com for programming questions.

Comment: ok, this i kind of embrassing, but they banned me there because my question had down votes :-(

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm sure it's only temporary. But, it doesn't make the question on topic here.

Comment: it's for ever, well was really important for me but what can I do. Thanks

Comment: Looks procedural, run the game and record the output.

Comment: the problem is I don't know how to run this file, this is just a 'rip' from a game and I want to 'play' the code. I searched for a converter or compiler but I didn't find anything.

Comment: I found something ! There is a program which is called mid2agb, and it contains a file called MPlayDef.s! With this in combination with a program called flat assembler you could compile it. Well, the mid2agb and the file that comes with the program seems to be illegal so I will keep my hands off it. Thanks for youre help, and @Byte65 thanks for supporting me on stack overflow